# C array of structs initialization issues when using macros

Tags: c, arrays, macros, struct

Why is adsafe_tags[1] is not getting properly initialized?

```
// local string (via static)
#define SSTRL(varname, val) \
    static const char varname[] = val

#define SSTRLEN(var) \
    (sizeof(var) - 1)

struct scs_data_tag
{
    uint16_t key_size;
    uint16_t val_size;
    char     data[];
};

SSTRL(ADSAFE_KEY, "p.as.rsa");
SSTRL(ADSAFE_VAL_BAD, "0");
SSTRL(ADSAFE_VAL_GOOD, "1000");
#define ADSAFE_KV_BAD "p.as.rsa0"
#define ADSAFE_KV_GOOD "p.as.rsa1000"

struct scs_data_tag adsafe_tags[] = {
    {SSTRLEN(ADSAFE_KEY), SSTRLEN(ADSAFE_VAL_BAD), ADSAFE_KV_BAD},
    {SSTRLEN(ADSAFE_KEY), SSTRLEN(ADSAFE_VAL_GOOD), ADSAFE_KV_GOOD}
};
```

and in gdb I get this:

```
(gdb) p adsafe_tags
$7 = {{key_size = 8, val_size = 1, data = 0x8ce664 <adsafe_tags+4> "p.as.rsa0"}, {key_size = 11888, val_size = 29537, data = 0x8ce668 ".rsa0"}}
```

Comment: `char data[];` is this allowed in C?

Comment: How will compiler know how much stack memory to allocate for one node of type `struct scs_data_tag` if size of `data` isn't sepcified

Comment: @MadHatter this is a "flexible array member" and is used by "overallocating", e.g. `struct s *p = malloc(sizeof *p + n * sizeof *p->fam);`. Before C99 introduced FAMs, something similar to this was someties called "the struct hack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the size of the `data` member of `struct scs_data_tag`. This declares a C99 [flexible array member](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472c/BABECHJI.html). This member has size 0 by default, and you'd need to `malloc` more than the actual struct size in order for it to be able to contain data.

According to the standard, it should not be possible for `struct scs_data_tag` to be an element of an array (because it contains a flexible array member). But this is supported by some compilers as an extension.

If you instead give this array a large enough size (e.g. `char data[40]`), your code should work.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that empty brackets is valid in C (C99).

Comment: ...or, if it doesn't have to be modified, `const char * data` which then points to read-only space.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to *interjay*'s answer,. You see `adsafe_tags[1].key_size = 11888` which is `0x2e70` in hex, which denotes ASCII characters `p` (= `0x70`) and `.` (= `0x2e`), therefore `"p."`.

Similarly, `adsafe_tags[1].val_size = 29537`, which is `0x7361` or `"as"`, rest is printed correctly as a string.

This shows that no space is allocated to `adsafe_tags[0].data`.

The string you provided for initializing it got mapped to next data set.